# Common code base for HTML5/CSS/JS webapp and native app

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova

I have been asked to create a webapp and native apps using HTML5/CSS/JS.

I should make some research, but i remember I heard about [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

My basic question is this:
if i write a HTML5/CSS/JS that somehow interacts with a server backend (through webservices for example), this is a web application that a user can reach with a browser (or mobile browser) at a specific IP addresss.

If I "phonegap" the same code do I obtain an Android od iOS application that is already working or is there some more work in between? IF there is some more work this is not clear to me.

I am aware this is a generical question, anyway it is a programming question because I need to know if going for this single code base is an option or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely off-topic for SO BUT! I have some experience with Phonegap and there is a little bit of work involved between coding your app and exporting it to an APK/whatever Apple use. You need an Apple Developers license to be able to sign the package to even test it on your iDevice, but with the others you can build the package install and go. You also have to be aware that not everything that a browser will do will happen on the device. But there is a ton of documentation on their site. I suggest you go look there first and if/when you get a problem, ask about that here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently built a hybrid web application using the same codebase that had to work on all major desktop browsers (down to IE8), mobile browsers and be installed as a "native-like" app on iOS and Android. For this I used jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap Build.

You can only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript for PhoneGap applications, so any data being retrieved from the server needs to be done via AJAX, but it works just fine.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Of course I said "native-like" simply because it's an installable app, but of course it isn't comparable to a native app, but I suspect you know this.